# dojo TabContainer does not return a selected TabPanel from a failed Submit

Tags: javascript, dojo, xpages, tabcontainer

I have a djTabContainer that contains several tabPanels:
[image: TabContainer Data Entry]

Works fine however, when I click the submit button I do some processing in a QuerySave and return false I get this view:
[image: Return from Failed QuerySave]

If I click on the Customer Tab it displays the customer info correctly and if I then click the Header tab it also displays correctly:
[image: Header Selected]

I'm assuming it is because on the return there is no tab selected, but not sure how to force it to display the Header tab on the return from the failed QuerySave.

Comment: The Header tab looks selected to me. Do you have any render logic for the content of the Header tab pane?

Comment: Per - There is some render logic inside the tab on a couple fields but nothing that impacts the whole tab or on the tab itself, and yes it looks like the Header Tab is selected. if I select one of the other tabs they display correctly and I click back on the Header it displays correctly. It is sort of like it is selected but it is not displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had two panels in the Header tab. The first one contained the error message and the panel is rendered if viewScope.vsError != null, and the second one has no rendered property. What I did was moved the error panel inside the header panel and that seems to have fixed it. I guess the tab did not like the rendered on the panelError.
In anycase it is working the way I want it to now.
Thanks to Per it was a rendering issue, but not where I thought it would be.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have a form tag inside that Tab. It will redirect once the form is submitted. You have to handle it your way to prevent it.

Lets say, if "myForm" is your form id,

```
dijit.byId('#myForm').on("submit", function () {
 sendFormToBackEnd(); // this will handle the POST functionality in js
 return false; //return false so it wont redirect now
});
```

Or the simplest one is append false in the call itself.

```
<form ... action="callSubmit();return false;" >
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to use form submit buttons. Instead, use a regular button with Dojo's iframe request:

```html
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/From" data-dojo-id="myForm">
  
  <!-- other form fields here -->
  
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">
    <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onClick">
      // manually activate validation
      if (!myForm.validate()) {
        return;
      }
    
      require(["dojo/request/iframe"], function(iframe) {
        iframe("yourUrl", {
          // not sure if you can use the From widget directly
          form: myForm.domNode
        }).then(function(data) {
          // ...
        }, function(err) {
          // ...
        });
      });
    </script>
    Submit
  </div><!-- Button -->
</div><!-- Form -->
```

You obviously don't have to use the markup `data-dojo-event`, and can simply put it all in a function to be called `onClick`.